# How to synthesis verilog cores made in xilinx core generator?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, synthesis, hdl

I used coregen to develop a divider core. Here are the steps I tried to use that divider in my design (not sure if its quite correct):
1) copied wrapper (core_name.v), .ngc file, and .veo file into main design folder
2) instantiate the core in my main verilog module using the veo template: core_name u1(.a(a_p), .b(b_p), .c(c_p), .d(d_p); whenever I need the divide function in my main verilog module
3) `include "core_name.v"

When I do a syntax check I get:
"core_name.v" line 1 expecting 'endmodule', found 'module'

Please advise on the steps needed to instantiate the core in my ISE design and synthesize it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that `core_name.v` is a full module definition, and that you've put the ``include "core_name.v"`within another module definition (ie, between`module`and`endmodule`statements.  (I'm thinking this because the verilog parser will want to see an`endmodule`sometime after a`module`, but instead is seeing another`module`in`core_name.v`).

Try putting the ``include` outside your module definition, eg

```
`include "core_name.v"
module toplevel_module ( );

  core_name U0 ( .. );
endmodule
```

instead of what I assume you have:

```
module toplevel_module ( );
`include "core_name.v"
  core_name U0 ( .. );
endmodule
```